# Why I am getting "Select.js:1555 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSelectOptGroup' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to show dynamic values in the dropdown by fetching from the dummy api . But I am getting error with select.js and my web page is displayed blank.

```
  class Test extends React.Component
    {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {  
                      dropdown:[]
                    };
       this.getJSONdata=this.getJSONdata.bind(this);
    }
         componentWillMount() {
          this.getJSONdata();
        }
       getJSONdata()
        {
          var temp=[];
          fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((myJSON)=>
          {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(myJSON));
            for(let i = 0; i<15;i++)
            {
            var data = myJSON[i];
            var joined = {value:data.employee_name};
            temp.push(joined);
            }
            console.log("obtained jSON data" +  JSON.stringify(temp));
            this.setState({
              dropdown:temp});

            });
          }
        render()
         {
            return (
                  <select
                   id =  "test"  
                   options={this.state.dropdown}
                 </Select>
            );
    }

export default Test;
```

On running I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSelectOptGroup' of
>   undefined

Where I am going wrong? Could anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: When it is telling you **Cannot read property 'isSelectOptGroup'**, put this part of your code in the example. There is no **isSelectOptGroup** in your example

Comment: where is `isSelectOptGroup` ? update your code or question accordingly

Comment: Perhaps you are using <select> instead of <Select> component?

Comment: I think you are using a library for your `Select` component, could you specify which library is it? If it is a custom component created by you, could you paste the code of such component?
It looks like something is missing in the options you are passing to that component.

Comment: I think its is something related to <Select> </Select> between where I am trying pass dropdown values to the options if i am not wrong. @josemartindev

Comment: I am using antd for Select.                                                                               
import { Select } from "antd";  //this way I am trying to import
const { Option} = Select;                                                                                                On running the code, console is saying error in Select.js (Its the js class from Antd). @mgarcia

Comment: It is a typo when posting the code here. I have used <Select> only  :) @noobprogrammer

Comment: https://ant.design/components/select/ Antd's ``Select`` component does not have an options prop

Comment: yes right. I am wrong at this point. How can I assign my dropdown array to Select component, so that it shows the dynamic value from the api. I tried doing                          <Select> <Option value = "options">{this.dropdown} </Option> </Select>. I think it is a dumb try. Still am getting errors. Could anyone help me with passing dynamic values to antd Select component. @josemartindev

Comment: You have to create an `Option` for each item in your `dropdown` array. Since your `dropdown` is an array, you could do so using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and returning an `Option` element for each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Its late but I hope it helps,If you are using AntD

You have written your select component wrong. Ant Design select doesn't have options props.
change your code to this.

```
       <Select
         value={this.state.yourValue}
          onSelect={this.onValueSelected}>
          {
            this.state.dropdown.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                return <Option key={index} value={item.value}>
                             {item.label}
                                 </Option> })
             }
        </Select>
```

And if you write anything else between `<Select> </Select>` you will get the same error